# Windows 8 minimum screen resolution

Tags: display, resolution, windows-8-preview

I had lately switched from Windows 7 starter to Windows 8 which works best on 1024*768.  My current screen resolution is 1024*600 - is there any possibility of improving this?

Answer (score 1):

The metro interface and metro apps support a minimum of 768 vertical resolution.  This isn't what is best, but a specific requirement.

Your screen resolution simply isn't supported in Windows 8.  If you are running the developer edition, there are hacks to restore the start menu, however this is no longer possible in Consumer Preview as it is no longer part of the build.

Answer (score 0):

I bypassed the requirements by virtualizing a computer that meets the system requirements and installing to it, then using VirtualBox CloneHD to create a RAW image which I wrote to my hard disk - this worked for bypassing the RAM requirement, for a time.

Of course, you need another computer to do this - I had access to a computer that I only have user priviliges on with nicer specs to do this.